# Integral $\int_{-1}^1 x \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Right now I am trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{-1}^1 x \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$$

So I have been trying to rationalize and simplify this since it looks to me that it will be reduced to trigonometric functions. I tried first to take the squared root from the nominator and separate the integral to a sum of the following two integrals:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx + \int_{-1}^1 \frac{{-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

However, I am stuck at this part. Does anyone have any idea of other properties I can use to simplify this integral? The first one looks like can be solved by substitution but the second integral still needs to be rearranged. Thanks!

Comment: The domain of integrand in $\int_{-1}^1 x \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$ is $[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Try $x=\cos{t}$, where $0<t<\pi$.  It must help.

Comment: So the interval 0<t<π would be the new limits of integration?

Comment: @user3563945 Yes, of course.  From $\pi$ to $0$. Also $t=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$ works.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of the integrand in is $[-1,1]$ then for
$$I=\int_{-1}^1 x \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx$$
with substituting $x=\cos2\theta$ we have 
$$I=4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos2\theta\sin^2\theta d\theta=\color{blue}{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The integrand on the left is odd, hence this terms brings no contribution. For the right integral, use $-x^2=1-x^2+1$ and simplifiy. You will get an arc sine and the area of a semi-circle.

Answer (score 1):

Both
$$
\int_{-1}^1 (1+x) \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\int_{-1}^1 (1-x) \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx
$$
are Beta functions, and yours is a linear combination of them.

Answer (score 0):

By enforcing the substitution $\frac{1-x}{1+x}\mapsto z$ (notice that $f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ is an involution) we get:

$$ \int_{-1}^{1}x\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\,dx=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1-z)\sqrt{z}}{(z+1)^3}\stackrel{z\mapsto u^2}{=}4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^2-u^4}{(u^2+1)^3}\,du $$
and by integration by parts we get that the last integral equals
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-3u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}\,du =\color{blue}{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
since for any $a>0$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{u^2+a}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a}}\quad\xrightarrow{\frac{d}{da}}\quad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(u^2+a)^2}=\frac{\pi}{4a\sqrt{a}}.$$